# how to run a OAuthSwift demo in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode.

I have just downloaded and open the [latest release](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift/releases) (not the master branch or zip download) of [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift) project by dongri on GitGHub.

There is a Demo folder inside the project. But I could not launch it by clicking the Play button. What can I do to launch it in a simulator?

Thank you so much.

[image: Xcode showing Build Succeeded]
[image: Project setting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to build a framework. To run the app select the right scheme:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need.